# Reading lines from a file

Tags: python, function, text, import

I am writing a program to read lines of text from 5 files and compile the text from these 5 files into respective lists.

However I am having a great deal of trouble getting the program to actually read the text to a list, here is my code so far:

```
from random import random

from dice import choose

b = open ('E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\ca2\beginning.txt', 'r'). readlines ()
stripped_b = [item.strip() for item in b]

a = open ('E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\ca2\adjective.txt', 'r'). readlines ()
stripped_a = [item.strip() for item in a]

i = open ('E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\ca2\inflate.txt', 'r'). readlines ()
stripped_i = [item.strip() for item in i]

n = open ('E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\ca2\noun.txt', 'r'). readlines ()
stripped_n = [item.strip() for item in n]

phrase = []

turn = 0

def business_phrase(x):

    x = raw_input("\n\nInsert a number of business phrases to generate: ")
    while turn <= x:
        turn += 1
        for item in stripped_b:
            random_word = choose(item)
            phrase.append(random_word)
        for item in stripped_a:
            random_word = choose(item)
            phrase.append(random_word)
        for item in stripped_i:
            random_word = choose(item)
            phrase.append(random_word)
        for item in stripped_n:
            random_word = choose(item)
            phrase.append(random_word)
    print random_list
```

business_phrase(x)

where beginning, adjective, inflate and noun are the text files and dice is a python file containing the function for choose.

I run this program to try and generate a phrase and I get the following error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename 'E:\\Videos, Tv etc\\Python\\ca2\\x08eginning.txt'
```

I have no idea why it won't read the text files as they are in the same directory as stated (in fact in the same directory as the program containing the function).

Does anyone have any ideas I am completely stumped.

Comment: Have you read the error yet? No, have you *really* read it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what it means, I am a complete beginner.

Comment: The `\x08` didn't trip any warning bells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'\' is used for escapes in Python strings. [Here's a list of what you can do with them](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). You want to escape the backslashes to actually have them read as backslahes, which means using two of them. Do this:

```
'E:\\Videos, TV etc\\Python\\ca2\\adjective.txt'
```

[Raw strings like larsmans suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154490/python-reading-lines-from-a-file/8154561#8154561) will also work!

Comment: I changed it to that, but now I'm getting the same as before + a syntax error. I'm so confused!

Comment: It's identical to the one stated in the question, but then it has SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the next line down. :(

Comment: Looks like it is still escaping the \b to make it a backspace. Did you try using a raw string?

Comment: It works now :D, only problem is it is printing single letters as strings indefinitely, and although I know why it is print indefinitely, I don't know how to edit it so that it doesn't. :(

Comment: My guess is that's happening because you are comparing turn, which is an integer, to x, which will be a string from raw_input and not an integer. int(x) will return the number conversion of x (but will cause an error if you enter a non-number!)

Answer (score 8):

when handling Windows pathnames, always use raw string literals:

```
r'E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\ca2\beginning.txt'
```

because otherwise the backslashes may be interpreted as starting an escape sequence.

Also, watch out with backslashes at the end of a string: `r'C:\'` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

No, you probably *don't* have a filename with a ^H in it. Escape your backslashes.

```
'...\\...'
```